# Express Morgan async use

Tags: javascript, express, morgan

I spent too much time on this, but I don't know if it's possible to do:
Make reverse lookup of IP and log it through morgan

```
Express.use(Morgan(async(tokens, req, res) => {
    async function ip_reverse_lookup(ip) {
        return hostnames = await dns.reverse(ip)
    }
    hostnames = await ip_reverse_lookup(ip)
    return hostnames
}
```

Now morgan just shows [object Promise] as output in console

Answer (score 0):

I try to unwrap Promise from mortan.token, but i failed.

First, I solved it by defining an async function, putting the corresponding value into req and using it in morgan.token.

```
app.use(async function checkDnsByIp (req, next){
  const dns= await dns.reverse(ip);
  req.dns= dns
  next()
})
app.use(morgan(...));

morgan.token("dns", (req) => req.dns || "");
```

Comment: It's obvious, but when IP defined inside Morgan it becomes less obvious

`Morgan((tokens, req, res) => {
 ip = tokens['remote-addr'](req, res)
}`
Still not sure what to do with it